# Input object of function will be overwritten by return

Tags: python, function, pandas, return

I am relatively new to Python and I have a problem with a function. Basically this function should edit a pandas dataframe and return it under a new object name. So leave the original object as it is. The returned object should be saved in a new object. My problem is, that the input object will be affected, too. How can I prevent my input object to be affected by the function, even if I save the result to a new object. I read something about immutable and mutable objects, but how do I change my function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

msg_items = pd.DataFrame({'Column_A': [10,20,30,40,50,60]})

print('Before: ', msg_items.dtypes)

def justdoit(myframe):
    cols = list(myframe)
    myframe[cols] = myframe[cols].applymap(np.str)
    return myframe

testframe = justdoit(msg_items)

print('After: ', msg_items.dtypes)
```

Actual output:

```
Before:  Column_A    int64
dtype: object
After:  Column_A    object
dtype: object
```

Expected output:

```
Before:  Column_A    int64
dtype: object
After:  Column_A    int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: `myframe[cols] = myframe[cols].applymap(np.str)` edits the original dataframe, it doesn't create a new one.

Comment: And how can I create a new one, instead of editing the original dataframe?

Comment: Don't use `applymap`, and use `copy` to create a new one (see my answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your aim is casting the dataframe to string without modifying the original, then you're not doing it right, because

```
myframe[cols] = myframe[cols].applymap(np.str)
```

1. Assigns the result back to the *original dataframe*, so changes are made inplace
2. Isn't the most pandaic way to caste columns to string

Further,

```
return myframe
```

Returns the *same* object, which you are just assigning to a *new variable*. There is only one dataframe, but two ways of accessing it, through two variables!

To pandaically convert a dataframe to string, use `astype(str)` -

```
def just_do_it(df):
    return df.astype(str)
```

If you want to edit a subset and return a copy, then call `df.copy` -

```
def just_do_it(df, subset):
    df_new = df.copy()
    df_new[subset] = df_new[subset].astype(str)

    return df_new

new_msg_items = just_do_it(msg_items, subset=list(msg_items))
```

```
msg_items.dtypes
Column_A    int64
dtype: object

new_msg_items.dtypes
Column_A    object
dtype: object
```

As a side note, if you have columns of mutable types, you might want to perform a *deepcopy*. In that case, call `copy` with `deep=True` -

```
df_new = df.copy(deep=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! You guys are awesome. Never expected such a complex case. I come from R and I tend to use just the arrow to copy an object.

Comment: @ErikSteiner Cheers, it's a common gotcha for all comers with python.

Answer (score 0):

in your function - create a new object with `copy.deepcopy(x)` and then change the value on it and return it.

```
def justdoit(myframe):
    cols = list(myframe)
    myframe_new = copy.deepcopy(myframe)
    myframe_new [cols] = myframe[cols].applymap(np.str)
    return myframe_new
```

Comment: Same as the other answer, `applymap` isn't a good method to use for string conversion. In fact, you're even using `copy.deepcopy` when you could just be using `df.copy`.